# $\log \log x^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\log (\log x)^2?$?

Tags: calculus

Is  this following true

$$\log (\log (x^{-1}))=\frac{1}{2}\log ((\log (x^{-1}))^2)=\frac{1}{2}\log ((-\log x)^2)=\frac{1}{2}\log ((\log x)^2) ?$$

Comment: In the range $0<x<1$, yes. But for $x>1$, the left-hand side is not defined.

Comment: $(\log (\log x))^{-1}$ or $\log (\log (x^{-1}))$ or $\log(\log x)^{-1})$ or..?

Comment: It is clear that it is $\log(\log(x^{-1}))$.  Fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote $$ \log\left(x^{-1}\right)=\sqrt{\log\left(x^{-1}\right)^2}$$
and then took the root out of the log. This is not always true, as a matter of fact 
$$\sqrt{\log\left(x^{-1}\right)^2}=\left|\log\left(x^{-1}\right)\right|$$

assuming you mean with $x\in\mathbb{R}$, your equality is only valid when $\log\left(x^{-1}\right)>0$, or $0<x<1$. You can already see this noticing that on the left hand side, if $x\geq 1
$ you have $\log\left(x^{-1}\right)\leq 0$, so you're taking the log of a negative number (or of $0$) which is not defined in the reals.